# unable to get power bi access token asp.net mvc with ping federate authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, saml, powerbi-embedded, pingfederate

I have an web app with ping federate authentication. Now I want to integrate power bi embedded into it. But I was unable to get access token from power bi, because my client has third party authentication like ping federate for power bi.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to develop your web application as an App Owns the Data Model with a Master Account or Service principal that is setup with appropriate permissions on the a Azure Admin Panel. See this link to determine which of those App Owns the Data Model approaches better suits your needs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-service-principal#service-principal-vs-master-account